# Where does Æmber captured from own side go after creature leaves play?

Tags: keyforge

I've got a card (`Mars Needs Æmber`) that has the following **play** ability:

> **Play:** Each damabed enemy non-Mars creature captures 1 Æmber from their own side.

I was wondering what happens when this creature leaves play? My interpretation of the rules would suggest that the Æmber would then go into the pool of the player who played the `Mars Needs Æmber` card. Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

From the rulebook (https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/products/keyforge/) page 6:
"When a creature leaves play, any Æmber on that creature is gained by the opponent."

Answer (score 3):

## No, but Yes!

It doesn't matter who played *Mars Needs Æmber*, all that matters is who controls the Martians when they leave play. There are a variety of effects that can temporarily gain control of a creature. Who the Æmber was captured from doesn't matter, only who controls the creature at the time it leaves play. Since *Mars Needs Æmber* doesn't deal damage, or remove creatures from play, once it's played, who played it is forgotten as far as the Æmber is concerned. This is a small, but important distinction!

Comment: captured Æmber always goes to the opponent of the card's owner when it leaves play, right?

Comment: Yes. In the exact situation you mention (with nothing else happening between) the answer is Yes...however it is important to remember that the Æmber goes to the opponent of the controller of the creature. Where it came from and who owns the creature are irrelevant.

Comment: My bad, I meant controller and not owner.

Comment: To be fair, usually the owner and controller are the same, the distinction is only important when someone is controlling one of their opponent's cards.